# How to Create a web form in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, web-tab

I am new sfdc development.I got a requirement like whenever any rep after created the quote he had to send that quote like a web-form to the client.It means i have to send that quote in a web-form(Like a web-link) to client through his mail id.whenever client had fill all the fields in the form and then click submit the details will be stored in our org.I had created a custom button to send quote.But,my problem is whether to go for web-tab or custom or another solution.

thanks in advance

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are designing solutions on force.com for these type of requirements ,first question thats important to consider is

1)Are your clients going to be Salesforce users?

2)If they are users what license will you allocate to their profiles.

3)How complex you want your user interfaces .Standard out of box or a custom visualforce ?

If your clients are SFDC contacts and you want a secure solution ,worth looking into communities licence types. One thing to look for is are quotes exposed in the licence type.

If you want to keep unauthenticated ,you can use force.com sites and you generate a link with ID sent in the URL .Use the Id to identify quotes.You may have to research a bit whether quotes are exposed in force.com sites.